# Regarding special characters in UILabel (probably something to do with encoding ? UTF8?)

Tags: objective-c, ios, utf-8, character-encoding, uilabel

I have something like :

"Jossmaisel ♡"

I want to show it in UILabel.But the special character shows up as two chars instead of the heart sign.

Is it something related to the encoding? Somehow I need to do something about UTF 8 ?

Can anyone kindly help me out ?

Comment: Is it a fixed string that you want to display? If not, where do you get it from?

Comment: @MartinR : Its not fixed. I get it from a server.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you escaped the heart character? As in `@"Jossmaisel \u2661"`? In UTF-8 encoding, it would take three bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so figured it out :

[From Here](http://www.dev-smarter.com/decode-an-utf8-nsstring/)

```
NSString *encoded_string = @"Ã¼";
const char *ch = [encoded_string cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
NSString *decode_string = [[NSString alloc]initWithCString:ch encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",decode_String);
```