# how to show special character in UIlabel in iOS like Ä’

Tags: ios, iphone

I am getting ARTÄ’ Madrid from database when I pass in uilabel it shows ARTÃƒâ€žÃ¢â‚¬â„¢ Madrid. Please help me

thanks in advance.

Comment: I am fetching data from sqlite

Answer (score 0):

Try to encode your string:

```
NSString *toEncode_string = @"ARTÄ";
const char *ch = [toEncode cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
NSString *decode_string = [[NSString alloc]initWithCString:ch encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

[from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12658743/regarding-special-characters-in-uilabel-probably-something-to-do-with-encoding)

Answer (score 0):

You can copy character from "ARTÃƒâ€žÃ¢â‚¬â„¢" and past on label text.

Comment: this is only an example there are lot of special caracters

Comment: You can copy from this site "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Latin_script".
"https://www.utexas.edu/learn/html/spchar.html"
"https://forlang.wsu.edu/help-pages/microsoft-keyboards-standard-english-us101/"